# Unexplained points of intersection of $f(x)$ and $f(\sin(\pi x)+x)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, roots, gamma-function, integers

To my knowledge,
$$\sin(\pi x)=0\iff x\in\Bbb{Z}$$
and thus
$$x=\sin(\pi x)+x\iff x\in\Bbb{Z}$$
. Using Desmos, I plotted two equations:
$$f(x)=\Gamma(x+1)$$
$$g(x)=\Gamma((\sin(\pi x)+x)+1)$$
and observed the points at which the curves intersect. I assumed that, since
$$x=\sin(\pi x)+x\iff x\in\Bbb{Z}$$
and therefore
$$f(x)=f(\sin(\pi x)+x)\iff x\in\Bbb{Z}$$
, all points of intersection would have integer $x$-coordinates. I was wrong.

It appears that the graphs do intersect at all positive integers (the gamma function is undefined at negative integers) but there is one 'extra' solution for positive $x$ near $(0.1912,0.9205)$ as well as seemingly infinite solutions for negative $x$. According to my hypothesis, there should be no solutions for negative $x$. How can these 'extra' solutions be explained?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The gamma function is not injective.

Comment: @Axel Why does that matter?

Comment: That matters when you try to show that $f(x)=f(\sin(\pi x)+x)\implies x\in\mathbb Z$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider $f : x \mapsto 0$. It is clear that $f(x) = f(x+\sin(\pi x)) \Longleftrightarrow x \in \mathbb{Z}$ is false. I mean $f(x) = f(x+\sin(\pi x)) \Longleftarrow x \in \mathbb{Z}$ will be true but not the reciprocal.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer. I'm still a little confused though, because $f(x)=x^2$ is also not injective, but there are no stray solutions. So what exactly is required of $f$ for $f(x)=f(\sin(\pi x)+x)\iff x\in\Bbb{Z}$?

Comment: That's right. Injectivity is only a sufficient condition but not necessary. I think it highly depends on how the function is defined. I can't help you more than that, sorry.